# Write-Progress not rendering at all when called in a loop

Tags: powershell

The script I'm working on is a ticket reserving bot for student events, it waits in the specified loop until sales start, and the write-progress is supposed to let you know when they do start. I'm fairly new to PowerShell and I'm sorry if the code is a sore for the eyes. I'm just baffled since this part did work earlier today, even though nothing about the loop changed iirc.

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
While ($currentDate -lt $purchaseTime){
  $currentDate = Get-Date
  $waitTime = (New-TimeSpan -End $purchaseTime).TotalSeconds
  Write-Progress -Activity "Waiting until sales start" -SecondsRemaining $waitTime
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
  If ($currentDate -ge $purchaseTime){continue}
}
```

I also tried this:

```
Do {
  $currentDate = Get-Date
  $waitTime = (New-TimeSpan -End $purchaseTime).TotalSeconds
  Write-Progress -Activity "Waiting until sales start" -SecondsRemaining $waitTime
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 201
} until ($currentDate -gt $purchaseTime)
```

I tried changing the loop from While to Do and even If statements but nothing changed. Can anyone solve this? I'm not getting any errors either, it just won't render.

EDIT 1
This is how the value is fetched, $jsonObject is made out of a GET request, and below is its value.

```
 
$purchaseTime = $jsonObject.model.product.dateSalesFrom

"2022-11-25T11:00:00+02:00"
```

The format shouldn't be the issue, since they've been the same throughout the process of me writing this script. And it used to with that formatting too.

I tried inserting the code suggested by Mathias before that declaration, but it didn't change the end result.
Did he mean I should insert it within the loop? Would that screw it up since I really need it to be this static place in time in order for the script to work as intended. My PSVersion is 5.1. Should I post the entire script for clarity?

EDIT 2.

I have implemented the code that Santiago suggested as the answer, but nothing has changed. The progress still won't render. Could the issue be with how the date from the jsonobject is formatted? The code Santiago posted runs and works on its own in a powershell instance, so I doubt my settings or anything like that is not working as intended.

Here is what the loop currently looks like:

```
$nowDate    = Get-Date
$targetDate = Get-Date $jsonObject.model.product.dateSalesFrom
$timeSpan   = $targetDate - $nowDate
$stopWatch  = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

Do {
    $progess = @{
        Activity         = 'Waiting until sales start'
        SecondsRemaining = ($timeSpan - $stopWatch.Elapsed).TotalSeconds
    }
    Write-Progress @progess

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
until($stopWatch.Elapsed -ge $timeSpan)
```

Comment: Could you please share an example of how the initial `$purchaseTime` looks?

Comment: Using `$purchaseTime = ($currentDate = Get-Date).AddSeconds(10)` as the initial values both examples work as expected when I try them out in either 5.1 or 7.2. Which version are you using?

Comment: If you try the 1 minute code from my answer, do you see a progress bar?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes if I run the separate 1 minute timer code in a powershell terminal it renders normally. I'm running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

##### Proof of concept

This example shows how you can achieve your your [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.3) (I prefer to use `do` in this case, though it could be done with a [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while?view=powershell-7.3) too) for exactly **1 minute** displaying a progressive countdown. I believe a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0) shines for this use case, and it simplifies the code a lot.

```bash
$nowDate    = Get-Date
$targetDate = $nowDate.AddMinutes(1)
$timeSpan   = $targetDate - $nowDate
$stopWatch  = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

do {
    $progess = @{
        Activity         = 'Waiting until sales start'
        SecondsRemaining = ($timeSpan - $stopWatch.Elapsed).TotalSeconds
    }
    Write-Progress @progess

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
until($stopWatch.Elapsed -ge $timeSpan)
```

---

Using this same logic, you would only need to change the following:

```bash
$nowDate    = Get-Date
$targetDate = Get-Date $jsonObject.model.product.dateSalesFrom
```

This would make your loop run until `Friday, November 25, 2022 6:00:00 AM`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

The problem lies within the `$progressPreference` variable. I had set it to silentlyContinue to help with WebRequests being smoother, but unbeknownst to me it also affected the `Write-Progress` cmdlet. It works fine now.